# Creating custom Task List Option Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add a Task List item in Visual Studio 2013 (Tools --> Options --> Task List.  The standard TODO, HACK, UNDONE and UnresolvedMergeConflict are present.

I'm creating a task item REFACTOR.  I add it per the (very simple) instructions and I see all of the items in my list as I expect.  However, whenever I close the solution and then reopen it, the task is gone from both the Options and of course the View Task List.

I've checked the settings file and this value is persisted after I close the solution, but at reload it appears that the settings file is not loaded.  I can't find any documentation on this issue, and, the few articles on creating a new Task Item are so blatantly straight forward that I don't think it's a PEBCAK issue.  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event anyone else has this issue (but it doesn't appear that they will, since I've had 0 response), I found that making the settings in TFS 2015, which I also have installed, solved the disappearing problem.  Don't know whether it needed to be in both instances of TFS, or whether the newer version ruled, but it solved my problem.